# Prestashop: not saving field

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm working in a Prestashop 1.6 module and I'm having problem with one field that seems not to be recognized. In the controller I'm using the `renderForm()` method to get the form and I define the field in the form like this:

```
        array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => $this->l('Message'),
            'name' => 'message',
            'required' => true,
            'hint' => $this->l('Message to be shown when the customer exceeds the quota '),
        ),
```

And in the model class I define it like this:

```
    'message' => array(
        'type' => self::TYPE_STRING,
        'validate' => 'isString',
        'required' => true,
        'size' => 4000,
        'db_type'  => 'varchar'
    ),
```

And then when I try to save the record I get this message: `Property QuotaModel->message is empty`

Am I missing a definition somewhere else? Can you see what I'm missing here?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you define public property for it in the class aswell `public $message;`?

Comment: @TheDrot no and I'm pretty sure that's what I forgot! Thanks again! Please post your answer so I can get you the points. I will be testing when I get home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the field as public property in your object model class.

```
class QuotaModel extends ObjectModel
{
    ...
    public $message;
    ...
}
```