# Prestashop 1.7.2: add 3 fields to contact us page

Tags: prestashop, custom-fields

I added 3 fields to the layout at \themes\classic\modules\contactform\views\templates\widget\contactform.tpl and they show up perfect.

I added these 3 fields to the DB table customer_thread.

Contact requests are saved into this table except for the 3 new fields.

I also changed the CustomerThread.php class in

```
public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'customer_thread',
    'primary' => 'id_customer_thread',
    'fields' => array(
        'id_lang' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
        'id_contact' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
        'id_shop' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
        'id_customer' =>array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
        'id_order' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
        'id_product' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
        'email' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isEmail', 'size' => 254),
        'tel' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString', 'size' => 254),
        'naam' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString', 'size' => 254),
        'voornaam' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString', 'size' => 254),
        'token' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => true),
        'status' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
        'date_add' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate'),
        'date_upd' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate'),
    ),
);
```

The 3 new fields are tel, naam and voornaam.

What am I missing ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013569/prestashop-not-saving-field/44026273

Answer (score 1):

Define its visibility:

```
public $tel;
public $naam;
$public $voornaam;
```

in `CustomerThread` class, before the definition.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, the model is right, database matches... but you still are not getting the form values.

Must go to modules/contactform/contactform.php (ps 1.7) and find **public function sendMessage()**

```
    public function sendMessage()
{
    $extension = array('.txt', '.rtf', '.doc', '.docx', '.pdf', '.zip', '.png', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.jpg');
    $file_attachment = Tools::fileAttachment('fileUpload');
    $message = Tools::getValue('message');
    //Add Here
    $tel = Tools::getValue('tel');
    $naam = Tools::getValue('naam');
    $voornaam = Tools::getValue('voornaam');

    //make your validations if needed

    if (!($from = trim(Tools::getValue('from'))) || !Validate::isEmail($from)) {
        $this->context->controller->errors[] = $this->trans('Invalid email address.', array(), 'Shop.Notifications.Error');
    } elseif (!$message) {
        $this->context->controller->errors[] = $this->trans('The message cannot be blank.', array(), 'Shop.Notifications.Error');
    } elseif (!Validate::isCleanHtml($message)) {
        $this->context->controller->errors[] = $this->trans('Invalid message', array(), 'Shop.Notifications.Error');
    } elseif (!($id_contact = (int)Tools::getValue('id_contact')) || !(Validate::isLoadedObject($contact = new Contact($id_contact, $this->context->language->id)))) {
        $this->context->controller->errors[] = $this->trans('Please select a subject from the list provided. ', array(), 'Modules.Contactform.Shop');
    } elseif (!empty($file_attachment['name']) && $file_attachment['error'] != 0) {
        $this->context->controller->errors[] = $this->trans('An error occurred during the file-upload process.', array(), 'Modules.Contactform.Shop');
    } elseif (!empty($file_attachment['name']) && !in_array(Tools::strtolower(substr($file_attachment['name'], -4)), $extension) && !in_array(Tools::strtolower(substr($file_attachment['name'], -5)), $extension)) {
        $this->context->controller->errors[] = $this->trans('Bad file extension', array(), 'Modules.Contactform.Shop');
    } else {
        $customer = $this->context->customer;
        if (!$customer->id) {
            $customer->getByEmail($from);
        }

        $id_order = (int)Tools::getValue('id_order');

        $id_customer_thread = CustomerThread::getIdCustomerThreadByEmailAndIdOrder($from, $id_order);

        if ($contact->customer_service) {
            if ((int)$id_customer_thread) {
                $ct = new CustomerThread($id_customer_thread);
                $ct->status = 'open';
                $ct->id_lang = (int)$this->context->language->id;
                $ct->id_contact = (int)$id_contact;
                $ct->id_order = (int)$id_order;
                if ($id_product = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product')) {
                    $ct->id_product = $id_product;
                }
                $ct->update();
            } else {
                $ct = new CustomerThread();
                if (isset($customer->id)) {
                    $ct->id_customer = (int)$customer->id;
                }
                $ct->id_shop = (int)$this->context->shop->id;
                $ct->id_order = (int)$id_order;
                if ($id_product = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product')) {
                    $ct->id_product = $id_product;
                }
                $ct->id_contact = (int)$id_contact;
                $ct->id_lang = (int)$this->context->language->id;
                $ct->email = $from;
                //Add Here
                $ct->tel = $tel;
                $ct->naam = $naam;
                $ct->voornaam = $voornaam;
                $ct->status = 'open';
                $ct->token = Tools::passwdGen(12);
                $ct->add();
            }//......etc
```